# Ideal quotient (or ideal saturation) and p-adic valuation.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, dedekind-domain

It is from Serre's local field. Let $a$ and $b$ be two fractional ideals of Dedekind domain $A$, then $v_p((a:b))=v_p(a)-v_p(b)=v_p(ab^{-1})$.

I can understand the last equality without difficulty. However, to show the first equality, I considered showing $(a:b)b=a$, but could not find a way to start... I'm aware $(A:a)=a^{-1}$ for any fractional ideal $a$ but I don't think the same argument would apply here.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Localize at $p$, then your ring is a DVR and $(a:b) = ab^{-1}$ jumps out by writing them as principal ideals. Your last equality is in a sense not helpful because the easiest way to prove it is by localizing, and in the course of going through that proof you will reprove $(a:b) = ab^{-1}$.

Comment: @TokenToucan Yeah, in the end I just argued locally we would have $a_p=\pi^nA_p$ and $b_p=\pi^mA_p$ then $(a_p:b_p)$ must be $\pi^{n-m}A_p$, where $\pi$ is a uniformizer  after localization. Guess this is basically what you mean?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly it.